# stuck on component building react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZjyx.png)[image: uncaught syntax error]

I'm new to react and am an apprentice web/app developer and was wondering if anybody could help me with this the console says there is an error on line 5 and I can't seem to work out what I have done wrong

Comment: one needs to include a special plugin that parses jsx into javascript. It seems you use jsx to output html but jsx is not parsed by default

Comment: Your code has not been compiled to JavaScript and is still using JSX which the browser is not expecting. See [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) for a bit more information about JSX.

Comment: for example babel has a jsx plugin. To use react directly in the browser one would need a special build of react, but it is not recommended for production instead one builds a compiled javascript using react and transpilers like babel

Comment: Your file also needs to be a `.jsx` file for your IDE to pick up the HTML.